# Why does this function print 1 2 3 4 5 in ascending order

Tags: c++, recursion

I tried searching the answer but was not able to get any convincing answer. Can someone please explain me how does this c++ code print `1 2 3 4 5`?

I understood up until the point when `n=1`. when `n=1`, `fun(n-1) = fun(1-1) = fun(0)` is not executed as `n>0` is not satisfied, hence now `cout << n << endl` will be executed and `n` is still equal to `1` but then after printing `1` it should stop ? How does it go to the previous calls? How does it print `2 3 4 5`?

Also when `cout << n << endl` is above `fun(n-1)` it makes sense as it prints `5 4 3 2 1`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        fun(n - 1);
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    fun(x);
}
```

The above code prints `1 2 3 4 5` while from my understanding it should only print `1`.

Comment: Try to work it out when `n=2`.

Comment: .... aren't you curious to see what the values are on the way to surprise? Print the values (or debug the program).

Answer (score 5):

At every call of function `fun()` make a note of value of variable `n` and you can trace the output easily. When the recursive call to `fun()` return, the statements after it will be executed (w.r.t. function `fun()` it is `cout << n << endl;` statement). It work like this:

```
fun(5)    -->   First call : n is 5
5>0 : true
|   fun(5-1)    --> Recursive call 1 : n is 4
|   4>0 : true
|   |   fun(4-1)    --> Recursive call 2 : n is 3
|   |   3>0 : true
|   |   |   fun(3-1)    --> Recursive call 3 : n is 2
|   |   |   2>0 : true
|   |   |   |   fun(2-1)    --> Recursive call 4 : n is 1
|   |   |   |   1>0 : true
|   |   |   |   |   fun(1-1)    --> Recursive call 5 : n is 0
|   |   |   |   |   0>0 : false  --> Return from call 5
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   Print n (n is 1) and return from call 4
|   |   |   Print n (n is 2) and return from call 3
|   |   Print n (n is 3) and return from call 2
|   Print n (n is 4) and return from call 1
Print n (n is 5) and return from first call to main()
```

Hence, the output is `1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Amazing H.S. Understood. Thank you !!

Comment: If you're satisfied, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to recognize here is that the `fun()` recursive function prints the value *after* making the recursive call.  So this is what is actually happening:

```
call fun(5) from main()
call fun(4) from fun()
call fun(3) from fun()
call fun(2) from fun()
call fun(1) from fun()
return from fun(0)
print 1
print 2
print 3
print 4
print 5
```

That is, the print statements happen the recursive calls, beginning with the value at the bottom of the recursion, which is `1`, then backing out to `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the key here is that the function will continue execution **after** the recursive call, so:

```
fun(n - 1);
cout << n << endl;
```

will call `fun(n-1)` and **still continue the execution** of `cout << n << endl;` after `fun(n-1)` returns. It doesn't just go away. It only *postpones* the execution of writing to `cout` until after the recursive call returns.

It is unclear to me what you wish to accomplish with this recursive function, but if you want to only print `1`, you will need to encapsulate it in an `if` statement:

```
if(n == 1) {
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Or do something else to that effect. If that's not what you want, you may need to rewrite your recursive function completely (if you're not sure how to, you may need to ask another question explaining your needs more explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the execution:

```
int x = 5;
fun(5);     // Since x = 5
if (5 > 0)  // Since n = 5
fun(4);     // Since n - 1 = 4
if (4 > 0)  // Since n = 4
fun(3);     // Since n - 1 = 3
if (3 > 0)  // As before...
fun(2);
if (2 > 0)
fun(1);
if (1 > 0)
fun(0);
if (0 > 0)  // If fails, so function exits
cout << 1 << endl;  // Then returns
cout << 2 << endl;  // Then returns
cout << 3 << endl;  // ...
cout << 4 << endl;
cout << 5 << endl;
```

I always write down the execution in the above format when I'm trying to understand some complicated algorithm. The method works both for newbies and more experienced programmers.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the condition of end to (n >1) and then, you can have the result  [2 3 4 5]. see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJyZZeNfB).

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void fun(int n)
    {
        if (n > 1) {
            fun(n - 1);
            cout << n << endl;    
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        fun(x);
    }
```

Second, you can have the revese result [5 4 3 2 1] if you change the line position. see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk4sZeVzS).

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void fun(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0) {
            cout << n << endl;
            fun(n - 1);

        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        fun(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, rather than asking about this exact function. Please learn how recursion works. There are plenty of resources out there. You can also follow: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/